# Find $\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac{1}{k_1!\cdots k_n!}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Problem:** For fixed $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, find
>   $$\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac{1}{k_1!\cdots k_n!}$$
>   where the sum is over all integers $k_i\geq 0$ such that $k_1+\cdots+k_n=m$.

I tried to come up with a series with the above coefficients, but I failed.

Comment: Hint: [Multinormial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: Please don't accept answers so quickly. This will prevent people from adding other good answers, which would be useful to not just you, but future folks who have this question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multinomial theorem says that
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)^m=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac{m!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_n^{k_n}
$$
Therefore
$$
(\overbrace{1+1+\dots+1}^{n\text{ ones}})^m=\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac{m!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}\frac1{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_n!}=\frac{n^m}{m!}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Using power series (which is what I presume you were trying to use?):

$$e^{nx} = \left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{x^n}{n!} + \dots\right)^n $$

The coefficient of $x^m$ in the right side is your expression.

The left side is

$$e^{nx} = 1 + nx + \frac{(nx)^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{(nx)^m}{m!} + \dots$$

The coefficient of $x^m$ is $$\frac{n^m}{m!}$$

*Note: we used the power series for $e^x$.*

Comment: This approach can be used to prove binomial/multinomial theorem, if you so choose to...

Comment: Nice approach (+1)